# iOS 8 UISearchController's searchBar overlapping tableVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've making practises to use iOS 8 new features - UISearchController to display my tableView and result. But something strange happened. It seems like the searchBar is transparent.

Yes, the searchBar is overlapping with the tableView.  I've search a lot in SO, but no help.

[image]

My implementation in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_myTableView.delegate = self;
_myTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:_myTableView];

self.mySearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
_mySearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
_mySearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
_mySearchController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
_mySearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
_mySearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
[_mySearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.mySearchController.searchBar;
```

Did I miss something important?

Comment: try to add [_myTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)]

Comment: Try to create a UIView with rect (0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 44), put there your search bar and than set this view as tableHeaderView

Comment: @NilsHolgerson try both, not working.

Comment: @anatoliy_v try, seem likes the search bar is transparent

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've set `_mySearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal`. According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISearchBarStyle):

> UISearchBarStyleMinimal - The search bar has no background, and the search field is translucent.

Try deleting that line of code or setting it to `UISearchBarStyleDefault` instead.